# php form email hidden field value with array

Tags: php, forms, while-loop

I have a while statement in a loop that collects email from my database

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $email[] = $row['email'];
}
```

then I have PHP mailer as my mail out client. This collects a number of email addreses... about 50.

```
$mail->AddAddress("$email[0]");
$mail->AddAddress("$email[1]");
```

I then fill in the body with

```
$mail-> = "<form><input type=\"radio\" name=\"number\" value=\"1\" />";
$mail-> .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"number\" value=\"2\" />";
$mail-> .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=\"?\" />";
$mail-> .= "<input type=\"submit\" /> </form>";
```

I want to know how to send an email to the first person and have their email in the hidden field type... then to the next person send it to them and have their email in the hidden field. 
Is there any easy way to do this? I dont want to have to do it individually for each person.
I have tried while loops with increasing the array number $i++ but that doesnt do me any good. Anyone with any suggestions and it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a `while` loop you could try a `for` loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($email); $i++)
{
    $mail-> = "<form><input type=\"radio\" name=\"number\" value=\"1\" />";
    $mail-> .= "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"number\" value=\"2\" />";
    $mail-> .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"email\" value=\"$email[$i]\" />";
    $mail-> .= "<input type=\"submit\" /> </form>";
}
```

I am not too familiar with the `mail()` function but I'm pretty sure that the syntax `$mail-> .=` is incorrect. Perhaps you mean to use `$mail[$i] = "<form>...</form>"` as this should create an array of emails ready for sending. This purpose is only a presumption.

Comment: tried this and It doesnt seem to work because i send it two different emails and both produce the same result. I think I am going to try and create one big while loop throughout the whole page... thanks for the help @verbum